# Knowledge base id not getting generated using REST API call

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I am using QnA Maker v4.0 REST API to create a sample knowledge base but post providing the required Host and Header and sending the request, below is the response received:-

```
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 77
apim-request-id: bfb0bee2-6ec3-4df6-ab75-ac5f97c84c2e
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Date: Sat, 20 Jun 2020 20:50:18 GMT
Location: /operations/b41342ba-54d9-4096-89f9-a1451afa8af3
Content-Length: 252
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "operationState": "NotStarted",
  "createdTimestamp": "2020-06-20T20:50:19.2105184Z",
  "lastActionTimestamp": "2020-06-20T20:50:19.2105184Z",
  "userId": "b7b33a0d66b44c4699d5608fea98ab4e",
  "operationId": "b41342ba-54d9-4096-89f9-a1451afa8af3"
}
```